# Category name is not shown after saving category in backend Magento 2

Tags: magento2, data-migration, magento2.1

I migrated my categories from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2 and I try to create sub-category from the backend, but the category's name is not shown. If you edit any category attributes it's not saving.

[image: category_issue]

I searched on internet, and I found this question in magento.stackexchange but no answer is there.
[Magento StackExchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/205886/category-name-is-not-show-after-save-category-in-backend-in-magento-2)

Comment: maybe related: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110063/product-not-show-in-category-page-in-magento-2-0-2

Comment: I tried but its not working.

Comment: let try with remigrage again

Comment: The solution described here resolved this for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49252539/category-name-is-not-shown-after-saving-category-in-backend-magento-2

Answer (score 1):

I have found one solution for this. It's working fine for me.

For the category name you need to check your "Mysql Table => catalog_eav_attribute".

In This Table you need check two entry one for Attribute id 45 and another is 46.

If you have not found This then you need manualy Insert both of that.

Need to add three colum first is (attribute_id => 'Attributeid ex. 45 and 46', is_visible => 'Visitbility default ex. 1', search_weight => 'default ex. 1').

[image]

After that check.